# Consuming sales orders and invoices via the SAP Cloud SDK

Tags: odata, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-connector

I've managed to get the SAP Cloud SDK setup in TypeScript and have been able to successfully read customers (Business Partners) and products using the SDK.

Now I want to pull out the invoices and sales orders via these APIs. However, there are just so many APIs so it's very confusing. Can anyone point out where to look for or maybe give a sample of implementation?

Preference is to use the OData v4 Endpoints if possible!

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://api.sap.com/products/SAPS4HANACloud/apis/ODATA) shows all the S/4HANA Cloud APIs with a filter, OData v2.
If you prefer OData v4, here you [go](https://api.sap.com/products/SAPS4HANACloud/apis/ODATAV4).

You can type some keywords (e.g. sales order) there for further filtering and I found this OData v2 sales order [service](https://api.sap.com/api/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/overview).

Nevertheless, I'm not sure whether there is an OData v4 variant, that is available for the time being.